# Passing Runnable instance in another Runnable implementing class, where run() method of former needs a reference of later

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda

I have a class 'ResourceConsumerThread' that extends Thread and defines some behavior. Multiple instances of this class (i.e. multiple threads) will have different behaviors. I am trying to pass these behaviors through a functional interface (Runnable) while creating an instance of ResourceConsumerThread class. ResourceConsumerThread's run() method simply call the lambda's method - run(). However, my requirement is that the lambda i'm passing needs to reference the ResourceConsumerThread object to which it is being passed.

```
 public class ResourceConsumingThread extends Thread {
        //threads which have acquired resources that this thread is asking for.
        private List<ResourceConsumingThread> dependencyList;
        private List<Resource> acquiredResources;
        private List<Resource> requestedResources;
        private volatile boolean isDeadlockDetected;
        private final String id;
        private static int threadIdGenerator;
        private final Runnable runnableBody;

        private ResourceConsumingThread( Runnable runnableBody) {
            this.dependencyList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.acquiredResources = new ArrayList<>();
            this.requestedResources = new ArrayList<>();
            this.id = "T" + threadIdGenerator++;
            this.runnableBody = runnableBody;
        }

 @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running body for thread : " + id);
        if(runnableBody != null){
           runnableBody.run();
        }else{
            System.out.println("ERROR...threadBody can't be null.");
        }
    }
    }
```

user of this class will use it like below :

```
public void callerMethod(){
ResourceConsumingThread t1 = lockManager.createNewThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lockManager.acquireLockOnResourceForThread(new Resource(), t1);
            }
        });
}
```

But, since t1 is not built yet, i can't use it in the run() method - i'm getting compiler error.

Any idea how I can implement this, even if it involves some design rework? Major requirements are :

1. LockManager.acquireLockOnResourceForThread() needs to know which ResourceConsumingThread instance is requesting which Resource.
2. run() method of ResourceConsumingThread should be able to execute different logics in separate threads.

UPDATED with answer I'm trying (not sure if its right way of doing). Still waiting for additional angels on potential solution through the community.

```
final Map<String, Resource> resourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        resourceMap.put("R1", new Resource());

        final ResourceConsumingThread t1 = new ResourceConsumingThread();
        Runnable t1Runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lockManager.acquireLockOnResourceForThread(resourceMap.get("R1"), t1);
            }
        };
        t1.setRunnableBody(t1Runnable);
        t1.start();
        t1.join();
```

UPDATED (after @Cliff's comments):

```
 ResourceConsumingThread t = lockManager.createNewThread(() -> {

           lockManager.acquireLockOnResourceForThread(new Resource(), (ResourceConsumingThread) Thread.currentThread());
       });
```

Comment: The question is why does acquireLockOnResourceForThread need ResourceConsumingThread specifically? Could it get away with Thread.currentThread()?

Comment: @Cliff : interesting. Didn't notice that. Though i had to do typecasting as Thread.currentThread() gives instance of type 'Thread' whereas expected instance type is 'ResourceConsumingThread', its not a bad choice. Didn't want to change the type of thread passed into `acquireLockOnResourceForThread`, as it would require me to do casting somewhere else. Thx for highlighting this possibility.

Comment: Cool, again the actual question is why do you need ResourceConsumingThread? It'd be more ideal if acquireLockOnResourceForThread just worked off of the Thread base class. If not then you probably should consider using an interface which models the actual use case of acquireLockOnResourceForThread  here.

Comment: ResourceConsumingThread is a subclass of Thread class which tries to acquire a lock on resource. The goal is to have multiple threads acquire resources in a random order. Thus, i couldn't put this code within the run() method, coz that would have made the resource acquisition order static for every thread. Can you share some insight into what you are thinking around 'using an interface which models use case of acquireLockOnResource'?

Comment: (Sorry for late response.) The idea, or question, was how does acquireLockOnResourceForThread *use* ResourceConsumingThread? Which methods does it invoke? If those methods exist on base Thread class (which I assume they don't) then you can create an interface which defines these same methods. The method invocations that acquireLockOnResourceForThread makes on the ResourceConsumingThread are the "use case". Putting these same methods on an interface is how you "model the use case".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `this` in the anonymous inner class:

```
public void callerMethod(){
ResourceConsumingThread t1 = lockManager.createNewThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lockManager.acquireLockOnResourceForThread(new Resource(), this);
            }
        });
}
```

This will pass a reference to the `Runnable` that is known in the `callerMethod` as `t1`.

Comment: `this` would give me instance of Runnable() i.e. the parameter which is passed to the createNewThread(). But, I am looking for is reference of t1.

Comment: Ahh, right, there is a `lockManager.createNewThread`. Use a container, e.g. `Runnable[] container = new Runnable[1]; ... container[0] = t1;`

Comment: Thanks @Johannes. I tried a slight variation of your recommendation and also replaced `implements Runnable` by `extends Thread` to make the start/join convenient on my custom thread class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a functional interface that accepts the ResourceConsumingThread in its run method.

```
interface ResourceRunnable {
    void run(ResourceConsumingThread resourceThread);
}
```

Which would imply changing the Constructor of ResourceConsumingThread to accept ResourceRunnable. Then you could do:

```
public void callerMethod(){
ResourceConsumingThread t1 = lockManager.createNewThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(ResourceConsumingThread resourceThread) {
                lockManager.acquireLockOnResourceForThread(new Resource(), resourceThread);
            }
        });
}
```

Where ResourceConsumingThread would call ResourceRunnable.run(this) internally.

**Update:**
An alternate approach, as I suggested via comment would be:

```
ResourceConsumingThread t = lockManager.createNewThread(() -> {

           lockManager.acquireLockOnResourceForThread(new Resource(), (ResourceConsumingThread) Thread.currentThread());
       });
```